# function gets called several times

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to display a dataList. Some values are calculate from a function. It seems angular2 calls the calculate function many times.

```
  <tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
    <td>{{ data.no }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ calculateFunction(data.price) }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Console will output "calculate..." many times, more than dataList.length.

```
calculateFunction() {
  console.log('calculate...');
  return ...;
}
```

Should I worry about that for performance or just let angular2 do this?

Comment: Presumably something is triggering a model change, which causes it to run the function for all the elements again.  If it's a lightweight function, no big deal, if it's something more complex, probably better to try to handle it inside the component instead.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery There's just one thing trigger model change. dataList is undefined at init state, then assign the http result to dataList when request is finished.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `caculateFunction(data.price)` function will be called every time Angular runs change detection for the component (more precisely for the embedded view created by `ngFor`). This is because updating DOM is part of change detection and Angular needs to call `caculateFunction` to know what value to use for DOM update. And change detection cycle can run quite often. So if you have 3 items in the list and CD is triggered 3 times initially, you will see that the function is called 9 times.

If you inspect the updateRenderer function, you shoul see something along these lines:

```
function(_ck,_v) {
    var _co = _v.component;
    var currVal_0 = _co.calculateFunction(_v.context.$implicit);
    _ck(_v,3,0,currVal_0);
  }
```

Read more about how Angular updates DOM in [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d).

> Should I worry about that for performance or just let angular2 do
>   this?

If `calculateFunction(data.price)` returns the same result for the same price, it's better to calculate these values beforehand for each item and simply renderer them in the template.

```
<td>{{ data.no }}</td>
<td>{{ data.name }}</td>
<td>{{ data.calculatePrice) }}</t
```

In this way you will avoid performance decreasing function calls.

Answer (score 18):

You can change the components `changeDetectionStrategy` to `onPush`. after that, your **calculateFunction** function does not call several times.

to do that :

in your component:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush // this line
})

export class AppComponent {

  ....

  calculateFunction(value) {
    console.log('calculate...');
    return ...;
  }
}
```

and in your app.component.html :

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
  <td>{{ data.no }}</td>
  <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ calculateFunction(data.price) }}</td>
 </tr>
```

### UPDATED

The best way to handle this scenario is to use `Pipe`, like the following :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'handlePrice'
})
export class HandlePricePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(price: number): number {
    console.log('In Pipe ....');
    return price * 2;
  }
}
```

Then use that :

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
   <td>{{ data.no }}</td>
   <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ data.price |handlePrice }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The pipe approach is working fine without changing the default behavior of changeDetection. The first solution makes angular acts like a simple static html page.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (more generic than @Abolfazl Roshanzamir solution, which is of course valid) is using a method like you are doing **BUT** wrapping it in a Pipe.

Example:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'wrapFn'
})
/**
 * Wraps a function in a pipe to prevent the function from being called directly in the template.
 */
export class FunctionWrapperPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform<T>(value: T, func: (...x: any[]) => any, ...args: any[]): ReturnType<typeof func> {
        return func(value, ...args);
    }
}
```

and using it in your template like this:

...

```
<td>{{ data.price | wrapFn: calculateFunction }}</td>
```

...

So, in your component, your method will have to return a callback:

```
calculateFunction = (price: number): number => { return price * 2 }
```

Comment: This worked for me. Using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` had undesired effects, so this seems like a cleaner option.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
.
.
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush // this line
})
export class MyComponent {
}
```

adding change detection to the component decorator solved the issue for me.