# Angular event method getting called multiple times

Tags: angular

In my `app.component.ts` I am making an API call and fetching `userDetails`. I am then emitting this `userDetails`. I have subscribed to this `userDetails` in my `header` component. My header component uses `app-my-image-logo` component. On page refresh, API is called and userDetails are fetched. After that, event is emitted and therefore, `testnDisplay` method is called. But my problem is every few seconds, I get the following output on my console.

```
img   my-image-logo.component.ts:28
name  my-image-logo.component.ts:28
img   my-image-logo.component.ts:28
name  my-image-logo.component.ts:28
img   my-image-logo.component.ts:28
name  my-image-logo.component.ts:28
img   my-image-logo.component.ts:28
name  my-image-logo.component.ts:28
```

So, this method is getting called multiple times after frequent intervals but it should have been called only once.

**header.component.html**

```
<app-my-image-logo ></app-my-image-logo>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
        const self = this;
        this.userDetails = this.dataService.getUserDetails();
        this.dataService.userDetailsEvt.subscribe(
            function(data){
                self.userDetails = data;
            }
        );

    }
```

This is `app-my-logo` component.

**app-logo.component.html**

```
<img #imgDiv  [hidden]="testnDisplay('img')" >

<div [hidden]="testnDisplay('name')"
     ></div>
```

**app-logo.component.ts**

```
testnDisplay(type){
        console.log(type);
}
```

This is my `dataService`:

**data.service.ts**

```
setUserDetails(userDetails){
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
        this.userDetailsEvt.emit(this.userDetails);
    }

    getUserDetails(){
        return this.userDetails;
    }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
this.authService.httpPost("/auth/getUserDetails", payload).subscribe(
            function (data: any) {
                self.dataService.setUserDetails(data);
            },
            function(error){

            }
        );
```

Comment: Best approach to handle this scenario is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52027587/11457981)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because you are using the `Default` change detection strategy on your component. By default all components use this strategy which means that when Angular determines a component's state is dirty it re-renders the template and cause the `testnDisplay` function to be called. In order to remove the component from default checking you should set the strategy to `OnPush` which is much more perfomant because it only re-renders the template when one of the `@Input` properties changes. It is still possible to have the template re-rendered but it requires the component to tell angular when to do so. Example:

```js
@Component({
  /* ... */
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppLogoComponent  {
  testnDisplay(type){
    console.log(type);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Teddy, this is working but I am still confused. Why would `Default` category treat the component's state as dirty when no value is getting changed? `EventEmitter` is only changing the value once, so it should be called only once.

Comment: The default behavior says to re-render whenever Angular thinks that something could have changed. Angular thinks something might have changed after an event is fired, an XHR occurs, or a timer fires (basically all async actions). It uses zones to determine what components could be affected and then tells those to re-render. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html