# Angular 7 view initialization triggers calls multiple times

Tags: angular7

In `ngAfterViewInit()`, I'm calling an async method (tried with and without `await`) to initialize a table of meetings:

```
public async getMeetings() {
  this.pendingOperation = false;
  try {
    var { meetingsUrl, bearerToken } = await this.getMeetingsUrl();

    var authAndJsonContentHeaderOption = {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${bearerToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };

    var httpResult = await this.http.get<any>(meetingsUrl, authAndJsonContentHeaderOption).toPromise();

    this.meetings = new Array();
    httpResult._embedded.myOnlineMeeting.forEach(element => {
      this.meetings.push(element);
    });
    this.pagedMeetings = this.meetings.slice(0, this.pageSize);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.observablePagedMeetings.next(this.pagedMeetings);
    }, 100);


  }
  catch (ex) {
    this.errors = `Error: ${ex.message}`;
    console.log(`Error: ${ex.message}`);
  }
  this.pendingOperation = false;

}
```

As visible in the code above, the retrieved list of meetings is sent to a `Subject` so that the view can display it in a paginated material table.

`ngAfterViewInit()` is rather simple:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.filteredUsers.subscribe((filteredUsers) => {
    this.displayedUsers = filteredUsers;
  });
  this.matAutocomplete._keyManager.change.subscribe((index) => {
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.selectedUser = index;
    }
  });

  this.getMeetings();
}
```

HTML is:

```
  <table mat-table *ngIf="pagedMeetings" [dataSource]="observablePagedMeetings" style="width: 100%">
<!-- table markup -->
  </table>
```

The problem is that this `getMeetings()` is called multiple times instead of once.

So far I've tried:

- using setTimeout to postpone this call
- specifying ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush on this component (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267323/angular-event-method-getting-called-multiple-times)) to break out of a possible change-detection cycle.

**Edit:**

- Indeed, `ngAfterViewInit()` itself is called multiple times

Comment: Did you check if `ngAfterViewInit()` is called multiple times too? Also, you are not showing enough code.

Comment: There are different reasons for `ngAfterViewInit()` to be called multiple times. One of the common ones is an error in your template.