# Efficent way to call a function from a selected attribute in matchip angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have created a mat chip like below.

HTML

```
<mat-chip-list multiple>
    <mat-chip class="chip_margin cursor mt-3" *ngFor="let chip of chips" selectable="true"
     [selected]="isSelected(chip)" (click)="onClick($event, chip);">
   <span class="unselectableText">{{chip.ViewValue}}</span>
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

TS:

```
 isSelected(chip:any) {        
    return this.chipCollection.get(chip.value);
 }
```

**Problem:**

"isSelected" function is calling n number of times how to solve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that isSelected is called in the binding [selected]="isSelected(chip)" which means that every time that angular runs the change detection it gets called.

To avoid this you have 2 solutions, the first one is to compute isSelected in another place and store a variable.

The second solution could be to switch to the OnPush change detection but then  you must handle the fact that change detection will only run when inputs change.

Answer (score 0):

This has been cleared [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53267658/6513921) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207623/6513921) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64499550/6513921).

One of the fix is to execute the function in the controller (*.ts) during the initialization of the `this.chips` member variable.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
// assuming `this.chips` is initialized in a subscription

this.someService.getChips().pipe(
  map((chips: any) =>                    // <-- RxJS `map` operator
    chips.map((chip: any) => ({          // <-- JS `Array#map` function
      ...chip,
      isSelected: this.isSelected(chip)  // <-- introduce additional property
    })
  )
).subscribe({
  next: (chips: any) => this.chips = chips,
  error: (error: any) => console.log(error)
});
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<mat-chip-list multiple>
  <mat-chip 
    class="chip_margin cursor mt-3" 
    *ngFor="let chip of chips" 
    selectable="true"
    [selected]="chip.isSelected" 
    (click)="onClick($event, chip);"
  >
    <span class="unselectableText">{{chip.ViewValue}}</span>
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```