# Angular 7, function passing in html body getting called multiple times on page load

Tags: typescript, angular7

I am calling a runtime function in html to get values from API service call, but the issue her is the function is getting called multiple times.
Here's the sample code for better understanding:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
.....
        {{myfunction()}}
.....
</body>
</html>
```

Typescript:

```
import....
export class ..... {
myfunction(num) {
console.log("Sample value...");
}
}
```

I can see console message more than once on loading the page into browser. What is causing this and what is the solution where the function should executes only once in HTML? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Probably should use OnInit to initialize then link via the class member. https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Comment: this happened because of changeDetectionStrategy of angular. you can read more about changeDetectionStrategy   read this: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: might be this answer helps you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207357/function-gets-called-several-times