# Avoid html repetition

Tags: html, angular

I have the following html, `params.formGroup.controls[params.fieldName].value` is repeated in ngbTooltip and looks ugly, is there some way to re-write that line to avoid the repetition of `params.formGroup.controls[params.fieldName].value`?

```
<div class="svg-class">
    <svg [id]="params.id"
    [ngbTooltip]="allTrans[params.formGroup.controls[params.fieldName].value] ?
        allTrans[params.formGroup.controls[params.fieldName].value] :
        params.formGroup.controls[params.fieldName].value"
    container="body"
    triggers="manual">
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not very fluent in Angular, but an idea would be to modify that to `[ngbTooltip]=somefunction(params.formGroup.controls, allTrans)`. If somehow you can call a function at this point.

Comment: @LajosArpad: This would be a bad idea if OP is using default change detection strategy in their component. In that case the function would be triggered for each change detection cycle and might lead to performance issues. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207623/6513921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the `*ngIf` directive's `as` construct with the `<ng-container>` element.

1. `<ng-container>` is commented out in the final DOM and so does not lead to bloat.
2. Note that now you're implicitly checking if `params.formGroup.controls[params.fieldName].value` is defined.

```html
<div class="svg-class">
  <ng-container *ngIf="params.formGroup.controls[params.fieldName].value as fieldName">
    <svg [id]="params.id"
      [ngbTooltip]="allTrans[fieldName] ? allTrans[fieldName] : fieldName"
      container="body"
      triggers="manual"
    >
    </svg>
</div>
```

From Angular [v12.0.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1200-2021-05-12) ([#36528](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36528)) you'd also be able to use [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) instead of the ternary operator

```html
<svg [id]="params.id"
  [ngbTooltip]="allTrans[fieldName] ?? fieldName"
  container="body"
  triggers="manual"
>
</svg>
```