# Firestore causing ngFor loop to be called repeatedly

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in my .ts file:

```
ngOnInit(){
  const firebaseConfig = {
   HIDDEN
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const app = firebase.app();
  console.log(app);

  const db = firebase.firestore();
}
```

and the following code in my .html file:

```
  <div [(ngModel)]="myInput" ngDefaultControl *ngFor="let word of words; let i = index;" (ionChange)="inputChange($event)">
  <input class = "inputs" readonly (click)="test();endWord(); onFocus($event)" (keyup)="keytab($event, 1)" *ngFor="let letter of toLetters(word);" maxlength = "1" type="text"/>
</div>
```

For some reason, whenever I include the line of code `const db = app.firestore()`, the function `getLetters()` in the ngFor loop gets called repeatedly.

This is the funtion that's being called:

```
  toLetters(word) {
    console.log("In");
    var empty = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      empty.push(word[i].toLocaleUpperCase());
    }
    return empty;
  }
```

Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see any `getLetters()` in your code. Are you referring to `toLetters` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that!

Comment: @NickM did you check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207357/function-gets-called-several-times) - does it naswer your question?