# How can I removed white spaces from interpolation data in angular

Tags: angular, string-interpolation, removing-whitespace

HTML File -

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of consultant; let id = index">
              <!-- <td>{{ id + 1 }}</td> -->
              <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
              <td *ngFor="let client of allClients; let i = index;">
                <p *ngIf="data.id === client.consultants.id">
                  {{client.name}}{{i === allClients.length - 1 ? '' : ', ' }}
                </p>
              </td>
              <td>{{ data.address }}</td>
              <td>{{ data.email }}</td>
</tr>
```

Problem ->

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlZ8x.png)

I get output like mentioned in the image, and I don't know how can I remove this white space from here, kindly help me to set my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you have empty `<td>` cells for the falsy `*ngIf` conditions. Try to introduce a border to visualize the error.

To avoid it, you could wrap the `*ngFor` in a `<ng-container>` tag and place the `*ngIf` condition in the `<td>` tag. It'd avoid rendering empty `<td>`s.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of consultant; let id = index">
  <!-- <td>{{ id + 1 }}</td> -->
  <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let client of allClients; let i = index;">
    <td *ngIf="data.id === client.consultants.id">
      <p>{{client.name}}{{i === allClients.length - 1 ? '' : ', ' }}</p>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <td>{{ data.address }}</td>
  <td>{{ data.email }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: it just removes space from the first element but other comma separated elements have still spaces

Comment: @payal_harwani: Try to visualize the error with borders like I said. Try to see if empty `<td>`s are still rendered.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the whitespace surrounding client names, you can trim all whitespace groups to just one whitespace. You can do it using `replace` method: `client.name.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()`. `trim` is then used to remove the leading and trailing whitespaces.

In `*.component.ts` add:

```js
public removeWhitespaces(input: string): string {
  return input.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
}
```

In `*.component.html` use the function:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of consultant; let id = index">
  <!-- <td>{{ id + 1 }}</td> -->
  <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
  <td>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let client of allClients; let i = index;">
      <p *ngIf="data.id === client.consultants.id">
        {{ removeWhitespaces(client.name) }}{{ i === allClients.length - 1 ? '' : ', ' }}
      </p>
    </ng-container>
  </td>
  <td>{{ data.address }}</td>
  <td>{{ data.email }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 21 in [ {{client.name.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim()}}{{i === allClients.length - 1 ? '' : ', ' }} ] in /Users/aps/Documents/New VGA-front/vga_front/src/app/pages/Consultants/search-consultants/search-consultants.component.html@55:22 (" = index;">
                    <p *ngIf="data.id === client.consultants.id">
                      [ERROR ->]{{client.name.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim()}}{{i === allClients.length - 1 ? '' : ', ' }}
              ")

Comment: @payal_harwani please see my updated answer.

Comment: still it's not working dear I didn't get the output properly

Comment: @Damian-TeodorBeleș: Calling function in Angular interpolation is a bad practice. It might be invoked multiple times simultaneously. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207623/6513921) for more info.

Comment: @payal_harwani I updated the answer again, please give it a shot (changes in html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're accidentally creating a whole bunch of empty `<td>` elements. Try it like this and see if it's any better. this way you you don't create a td element when the data doesn't match

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of consultant; let id = index">
              <!-- <td>{{ id + 1 }}</td> -->
              <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let client of allClients; let i = index;">
              <td *ngIf="data.id === client.consultants.id">
                <p>
                  {{client.name}}{{i === allClients.length - 1 ? '' : ', ' }}
                </p>
              </td>
              </ng-container>
              <td>{{ data.address }}</td>
              <td>{{ data.email }}</td>
</tr>
```

It could also be you're just trying to fill in all the clients in one table cell i would do that like this

```
              <td >
               <ng-container *ngFor="let client of allClients; let i = index;">
                <p *ngIf="data.id === client.consultants.id">
                  {{client.name}}{{i === allClients.length - 1 ? '' : ', ' }}
                </p>
                 </ng-container>
              </td>
```